# Wordpress - display specific widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

I'm lost a bit.

Let's say I have a dynmic footer-siderbar. Easy so far.

```
<footer>
    <?php get_sidebar("name") ?>  
</footer>
```

Displys it in the footer.

But here we are. I want EACH widget inside of my grid:

```
      <footer>
         <div style="width: 100px:">
            <div style="width: 25%">First widget here</div>
            <div style="width: 25%">Second widget here<</div>
            <div style="width: 25%">Third widget here<</div>
            <div style="width: 25%">Fourth widget here<</div>
          </div>
        </footer>
```

So get_sidebar isn't an option now, since it displays all widgets in a row. And I don't want to edit widgets itself.

How they do that in themes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the 'the_widget' function for this:

```
<?php the_widget($widget, $instance, $args); ?>
```

More information can be found on the [Wordpress Codex - The_Widget reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget).

Comment: Nice idea, but as far as I know the_widget requires widget name as the first parameter and I don't know what will be the name of gadgets in the footer. I just have sidebar name.

Comment: Did you manage to use the_widget to display an existing widget (instead of creating a new one)? How did you achieve it?

Comment: what do you put in instance and $args? how do you know what to put.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good reference as well - [Function Reference/dynamic sidebar « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

If you use the method on that page:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
 <?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>
    <li>{static sidebar item 1}</li>
    <li>{static sidebar item 2}</li>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </ul>
```

You could then use CSS styling to position the sidebar widgets across the footer.

***Edit to include the following...***

Arras theme CSS:

```
#footer             { margin: 20px auto 0; width: 980px; background: #ECEBE6; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
#footer .widgetcontainer    { padding: 5px 10px; min-width: 150px; }
.no-js #footer .widgetcontainer { height: 190px; }
#footer .widgettitle    { background: none; border: none; font-size: 14px; color: #444; padding: 0 0 10px; letter-spacing: -1px; }
#footer .widgetcontent  { font-size: 12px; background: none; padding: 0; border: none; }
#footer .footer-message { margin: 0; padding: 10px 15px 0; font-size: 11px; }
#footer .footer-message p { margin: 0 0 0.5em; }
#footer .footer-message .floatright { margin-left: 20px; }
#footer-sidebar     { overflow: hidden; margin: 10px 10px 0; padding: 0 0 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; }
#footer-sidebar .widgetcontainer    { float: left; margin: 0; max-width: 250px; }
#footer-sidebar ul  { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#footer-sidebar li  { margin: 0 0 3px; }
```

Footer coding:

```
<ul id="footer-sidebar" class="clearfix xoxo">
        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer') ) : ?>
        <li></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

In the theme it then places the widgets across the page.

Comment: Thank you, have been digging Codex for a few hours now, but still no luck.

Comment: Also if you have a look at the Arras theme they are running the same idea across the footer - http://demo.arrastheme.com/

Comment: Yeah I know there's a few free themes doing this, but it's totally complicated, opened every file in library dictionary, but no luck. There are custom functions in footer that doesn't work outside of the theme.

Comment: Sorry, but your code includes the WHOLE sidebar in one ul element, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also use :

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout my new plugin that displays a specific widget.

Visit:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-instance/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Widget Options Plugin to restrict or control the widgets visibility on any pages and devices; available for free on the repository : https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/. Or try using `widget_display_callback` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_display_callback/ . I hope this helps.

```
function custom_display_callback( $instance, $widget, $args ){
    if( is_page() ){
        return false;
    }
    return $instance;
}
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'custom_display_callback', 50, 3 );
```

[image]